# AngularJS - ngRepeat not updated at element deleted in dictionary-like object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ngRepeat for `ul` lists like below

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" style="overflow:auto; max-height:180px;">
    <li ng-repeat="(k, v) in dataDict">
        <a href="" ng-click="$parent.dataField = k">{{v}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript code works like this:

```
app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.dataField = "";
    $scope.dataDict= {};
    $scope.addElement = function (key, value) {
        $scope.dataDict[key] = value;
    }
    $scope.removeElement = function (key) {
        delete $scope.dataDict[key];
    }
}]);
```

When I add an element it works ok.

When I delete it is still visible for user but not avaliable form javascript. How to make delete work work?

I've found that for standart arrays you can do it like `array.splice(index, 1);` but for dictionary like object this is not possible.

Comment: did you try adding a $scope.$digest(); after the delete?

Comment: I've tried it directly(throws that apply is in progress) and int setTimeout(nothing is thrown, but view is not changed)

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle, so we can more easily edit your code? I don't see where you call removeElement or addElement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turned out I had a `$watch` added on that dictionary-like object in child controller that unintentionaly re-added record on delete. Everything in angular works as it should after fixing `$watch` code.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say why this isn't working for you, but I'd guess that AngularJS uses some sort of caching mechanism which does not comply with calls to delete on an object bound with ng-repeat.

Here are some alternatives:

**Option 1:**
Consider using a list rather than object. Your code would undergo very minor changes - instead of repeating key/values of an object, you'd iterate a list of object which would have a key field and a value field. Pretty straightforward. Instead of deleting, you'd just splice the list as you mentioned in your question.

**Option 2:**
If you insist on staying with the key/value repeat method, consider replacing the object when calling removeElement with a new data dict which is equivalent to the previous one, minus the unwanted key - like so:

```
$scope.removeElement = function (key) {
  var newDataDict = {};
  for (var dataKey in $scope.dataDict) {
      if (key !== dataKey) {
          newDataDict[dataKey] = $scope.dataDict[dataKey];
      }
  }

  $scope.dataDict = newDataDict;
}
```